# HTML action redirect with GET values

Tags: html

Hey,
Im trying to use a HTML form to send user info to PHP
the problem is, it dosent redirect with GET info:

```
<form action="register.php?task=add" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br />
    Password Check: <input type="password" name="password_check" id="password_check"/><br />
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I think this might be because i have the method set to POST.
Is there anyway i can fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect with GET value"? Your code works fine for me, I can access both `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: I mean it dosent encode the URL with the "?task=add"

Answer (score 0):

You could set the method to "GET".

Comment: I'd rather not becuase theres lots of user data being sent, which would make the URL length insane

Comment: That's the only way to make it a GET request. Why do you want GET anyway? Is there a reason you cannot use POST?

Comment: If you're using PHP then you can access data submitted through a POST request with the `$_POST` superglobal, the same way as you would with `$_GET`.

Comment: i know all that but i'd rather have the action/task step in get and the user info in post. but if thats not possable then i'll haver to use POST then

Comment: I'm guessing that you're trying to avoid the "user hits refresh and gets confusing message about resubmitting form data" problem. You could try POSTing first, then sending a redirect to the client to a new page that shows the next step. The redirect will be fetched with a GET request so refresh will work happily.